# 'combine first' in pandas produces NA error

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, each with a series of dates as the index. The dates to not overlap (in other words one date range from, say, 2013-01-01 through 2016-06-15 by month and the second DataFrame will start on 2016-06-15 and run quarterly through 2035-06-15.

Most of the column names overlap (i.e. are the same) and the join just does fine. However, there is one columns in each DataFrame that I would like to preserve as 'belonging' to the original DataFrame so that I have them both available for future use.  I gave each a different name. For example, `DF1` has a column entitled opselapsed_time and `DF2` has a column entitled constructionelapsed_time.

When I try to combine `DF1` and `DF2` together using the command `DF1.combine_first(DF2)` or vice versa I get this error:  `ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer.`

Could someone please give me advice on how best to resolve?

Do I need to just stick with using a merge/join type solution instead of combine_first?

Comment: Isn't `combine_first` meant for patching data with overlapping rows? But in your case, none of the rows overlap. What is your desired functionality: to have `opselapsed_time` give `NaN` for the rows in `DF2`, and vice versa? Or something else?

Comment: Only one of the rows overlap- basically what I am doing is building an app to val cash flows.  I have 1 set of cash flows that strt on the same date and another set of cash flows that start on the date that the first set of cash flows end. Point is the csh flow need to be combined together into a contiguous series with dates as the index so I can then do the val, and the last row overlaps. I guess I could set it up so that the 1st date of the 1st row on DF2 is the next day after the last day on DF1/last row.   

What I would like to do is have opselapsed_time give NaN or zero as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Found the best solution:

pd.tools.merge.concat([test.construction,test.ops],join='outer')

Joins along the date index and keeps the different columns.  To the extent the column names are the same, it will join 'inner' or 'outer' as specified.